# How to substitute $x$ in a expression $f(x)$ but not calculate the value of the $f(x)$ at the point $x$?

Tags: output-formatting

I want to subtitute $x = 1$ into the  expression $$f(x)=x^2 + 3 (x^2 - m^2) + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$$ but I don't calculate the value $f(1)$, that is mean, I want $$1^2 + 3(1^2-m^2)+\sqrt{1^2 + 1}.$$ If I tried

```
f[x_] := x^2 + 3 (x^2 - m^2) + Sqrt[x^2 + 1];
f[1]
```

I receive

`1 + Sqrt[2] + 3 (1 - m^2)`

How do I tell *Mathematica* to do that?

Comment: Dirty trick : `f["1"]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
  f[x_] := x^2 + 3 (x^2 - m^2) + Sqrt[x^2 + 1];


  f[HoldForm@1]   (* thanks: @chris *)
```

or

```
  f[Defer@1]
```

> [image]

Comment: what's wrong with `f[Defer[x]] /. x -> 1` ? The order?

Comment: @chris, right!!! thanks