# How can I get the right hand side of a delayed expression?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Imagine there is a given function f, defined with `SetDelayed`, say

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2.
```

Is it possible to get rhs of this function before evaluation? For instance of f[5] I want to get expression

```
Sin[5]^2 + Cos[5]^2.
```

Comment: Somebody had nice suggestion with DownValues, but it disappeared. DownValues is very cool, but I guess my example is too simple. Because I want to extract previous inputs which obviously have executions. In[2]:=(Print[2]; 2+2), where I would like to get the full form of expression, e.g Print[2]; 2+2 without evaluating it.

Comment: See my answer - it gives you that. If you are interested in the input, use `DownValues[In]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Yes, off course, I was just playing in Mathematica with your suggestion. Thank you! Sorry for my delay :)

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about :-). There is no rush with anything here on SE, including accepting an answer. It is actually usually better to wait for some time, to give people an incentive to post alternative solutions.

Comment: You can see at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20236/how-to-substitute-x-in-a-expression-fx-but-not-calculate-the-value-of-the

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do

```
Hold[f[5]] /. DownValues[f]
```

which would return to you the r.h.s. wrapped in `Hold` - which you can then strip or do anything else with it.

Note that while this is a useful technique, in many cases it is not really needed, so I'd first reconsider the design of your functions, and only use the above if it is really necessary.As a light-weight alternative, you can use local rules (`RuleDelayed`), e.g.

```
ClearAll[f];
myFormula = f[x_] :> Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2;
```

Then, you get what you need simply by

```
f[5] /. myFormula
```

Answer (score 3):

The *general* from of this question is what prompted my question and self-answer:
[How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/334/121)

Using my `step` function from [that answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121) this is simply:

```
step @ f[5]
```

> ```
> Sin[5]^2 + Cos[5]^2.
> ```

The output is wrapped in `HoldForm`.  You could use e.g. `Defer @@` if you wish to change the head.

Again, the advantage to this method over working with `DownValues` is that it is a more general construct, and will work with other kinds of sets that produce `UpValues` or `SubValues` etc., as well as internal functions to the limited extent that is possible.

Comment: +1. But you should also mention a disadvantage: generally a single evaluation step will not be what we think it is - there is no easy and general mapping between the chunks of evaluation that we consider a single step, and the steps of Mathematica evaluator.

Comment: @Leonid conceptually this is true, but using my definition: the first step that transforms the entire expression, this has been acceptably predictable for me.  Can you give a counter-example where it behaves differently?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind now, but I recall that we discussed some such examples in the context of safe `ValueQ` function.

Comment: B.t.w., I have some time to chat now, if you wish.

Comment: @Leonid My memory is poor; I'll try to find that discussion.  I need to leave in a few minutes, so no chat now. :-/

Comment: All right, later then.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard regarding a counter-example, if you do step@f[5+5], you get f[10], whereas with the method of Leonid, you get the right hand side of f applied to 5+5. In order to get the same result with step, f should have a HoldAll attribute.

Comment: This step function also seems very useful. However, I needed to get an expression exactly as it was typed (up to interpretation form) for which DownValues really did the trick.

Comment: @Faysal That's not what I meant.  I'm sorry for confusing the issue by having these comments attached to this question.  What I meant was for *my* question I wanted "the first step that transforms the entire expression" and I believe my `step` function does that.  `f[5+5]` -> `f[10]` does not transform the entire expression so this is entirely expected.  I am asking Leonid (or you) for a counter-example where what is returned by `step` is not in fact "the first step that transforms the entire expression."  I hope that's clear now.

Comment: @Vladimir That's fine, and FYI I voted for Leonid's answer too; I just wanted to make you aware of an alternative that in my experience has value.